# String index out of range while sending email

Tags: python, django, email

I'm running into this error: [link](http://pastebin.com/hH1ZbeWZ), while trying to send mail with Django EmailMultiAlternatives. I tried searching for this error but no luck, also I tried removing or changing every variable for email, but with no luck.

This is the code:

```
def spremembapodatkovproc(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        req_id = request.POST.get('req_num', 'Neznan ID zahtevka')
        old_email = request.user.email
        old_name = request.user.get_full_name
        new_email = request.POST.get('email_new', 'Nov e-mail ni znan')
        new_fname = request.POST.get('fname_new', 'Novo ime ni znano')
        dokument = request.FILES.get('doc_file')
        komentar = request.POST.get('comment', 'Ni komentarja')
        # try:
        plaintext = get_template('email/usr-data-change.txt')
        htmly = get_template('email/usr-data-change.html')

        d = Context(
            {
                'old_email': old_email,
                'old_fname': old_name,
                'new_email': new_email,
                'new_fname': new_fname,
                'req_id': req_id,
                'komentar': komentar,
                'user_ip': request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR', 'IP Naslova ni mogoče pridobiti.')
            }
        )

        subject, from_email, to = 'eBlagajna Sprememba podatkov', 'eblagajna@ksoft.si', ["info@korenc.eu"]
        text_content = plaintext.render(d)
        html_content = htmly.render(d)
        print(text_content)
        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
        msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")

        msg.mixed_subtype = 'related'

        for f in ["templates\\email\\img1.png"]:
            fp = open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, f), 'rb')
            msg_img = MIMEImage(fp.read())
            fp.close()
            msg_img.add_header('Content-ID', '<{}>'.format(f))
            msg.attach(msg_img)
        msg.send()
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You have `to = ["info@korenc.eu"]` and you trying to wrap it in `[ ]` brackets while initializing `EmailMultiAlternatives` instance. Try to change `EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])` to `EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, to)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was with redundant wrapping list of emails in another list.

So basically variable `to = ["info@korenc.eu"]`, then when line run

```
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
```

it wrapped `to` one more time with `[ ]` brackets. and `[to] = [["info@korenc.eu"]]`, but it supposed to be simple list. So by changing the problem line to

```
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, to)
```

everything worked.